# UIRefreshControll no progress activityIndicator -> start immediately?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uirefreshcontrol

this is my simple code:

```
self.refreshControl = [UIRefreshControl new];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.myTableView addSubview:self.refreshControl];
```

or

```
self.myTableView.refreshControl = self.refreshControl;
```

refresh: method is calling when scroll offset of myTable is -1 (immediately !!), no progress indicator while pulling...

App is on iOS10.3 xcode is 8.3

I saw in Mail app and in a lot of samples on stack that UIRefreshControll before starting show activity like a clock and when it's completed start refreshing.

I have also try to put UIRefreshControll on UITableViewCOntroller, but I saw immediately complete spin and start immediately to refresh:

I'm getting crazy I was suppose is very simple but I can't show progress indicator, can you help me ??

Answer (score -1):

`UIScrollView` (and therefore `UITableView`) have a `refreshControl` property you set instead of adding it as a subview yourself. So:

```
self.myTableView.refreshControl = self.refreshControl
```

This should cause it to behave correctly.

Comment: no!

changing        
[self.myTableView addSubview:self.refreshControl];
with
self.myTableView.refreshControl = self.refreshControl;

has No effect :(

thank you for reply !

Comment: maybe the new iOS version or new xcode has a problem... I'm getting crazy